# Ionic + Angular Formating Date From Wordpress Rest API

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am brand new to Angular and Ionic and I am bringing events from my Wordpress site using the Rest API. Right now my date is displaying as 2019-10-06T17:30:23 and I am using  to display that date. But I am trying to have the date to just display the time in 12HR format.

So I am trying to get the 2019-10-06T17:30:23 to display just as 7:30 PM is there anyway I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: 17:30 => 5:30 PM ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Angular has the [Date Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) that you can use for displaying date/time in a different format.

For example:

```
{{ dateObj | date }}               // output is 'Jun 15, 2015'
{{ dateObj | date:'medium' }}      // output is 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'shortTime' }}   // output is '9:43 PM'
{{ dateObj | date:'mm:ss' }}       // output is '43:11'
```